# How do I run a node.js function that listens to a stream continuously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, stream

I have a file: `stream.ts`:

```
require('envkey')
import Twitter from 'twitter-lite';

const mainFn = async () => {
  const client = new Twitter({
    consumer_key: process.env['TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY'],
    consumer_secret: process.env['TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET'],
    access_token_key: process.env['TWITTER_ACCESS_KEY'],
    access_token_secret: process.env['TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET']
  })

  const parameters = {
    track: "#bitcoin,#litecoin,#monero"
  }

  const stream = client.stream("statuses/filter", parameters)
    .on("start", response => console.log("start"))
    .on("data", tweet => console.log("data", tweet.text))
    .on("ping", () => console.log("ping"))
    .on("error", error => console.log("error", error))
    .on("end", response => console.log("end"));
}

await mainFn();
```

When I run it with `tsc stream.ts`, it runs and instantly ends. But I want to keep this up and running forever. How would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this I am not sure if it will works

```
require('envkey')
import Twitter from 'twitter-lite';

const mainFn = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const client = new Twitter({
      consumer_key: process.env['TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY'],
      consumer_secret: process.env['TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET'],
      access_token_key: process.env['TWITTER_ACCESS_KEY'],
      access_token_secret: process.env['TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET']
    })

    const parameters = {
      track: "#bitcoin,#litecoin,#monero"
    }

    const stream = client.stream("statuses/filter", parameters)
      .on("start", response => console.log("start"))
      .on("data", tweet => console.log("data", tweet.text))
      .on("ping", () => console.log("ping"))
      .on("error", error => {
        console.log("error", error)
        reject()
      })
      .on("end", response => {
        console.log("end")
        resolve()
      });
  })
}

const main = async () => {await mainFn();}

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code there is no particular reasons for async/await, you should remove them, anyway I don't think this could be the source of the problem.

Have you checked you are able to connect? I suggest to add a [verifying credentials example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter-lite#verifying-credentials-example-user-auth) between `Twitter` constructor and `client.stream` call: an unsuccessful connection attempt could be the reason of the reported problem.

Last, if everything is ok, but your program continues to exit, just add something keeping the process alive, this line at some point of your main file is enough

```
setInterval(() => {}, 1000);
```

Hope this helps.